# MS SQL Pivot Tables : Empty Source

Tags: sql-server, pivot

I am trying to do an SQL Pivot, it works perfectly when there is data in the main table I am trying to pivot. I have simplified my problem to a User, Subjects, Results Dataset. I want to show a table with Subjects as rows with Users as columns and their results for those subjects in the cells. It should show all Users even if they have no results and all Subjects even with no results. I have it working except when there are no results at all, then it returns nothing. I want it to still show the rows and columns but just with null's in the cells, Any Ideas?

See SQL Fiddle Example http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/a1f9e/1

**Updated**

[This is how it should look when there are no results](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DPXBz.png)

Comment: So what's your desired output?

Comment: Select ISNULL(p.subjectid,0),ISNULL(p.Name,''), ISNULL(p.UserID), ISNULL(p.ResultFrom,0) (your code )

Comment: Not sure I follow @mohan111

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to change your query to this:

```
set @query = '
Select * From (
SELECT Subjects.ID, Subjects.Name, Results.UserID, Results.Result 
from Subjects
Left Outer join Results
On Results.SubjectID = Subjects.ID
) x pivot (max(Result) for UserID in (' + @cols + ')) p'
```

You need to left outer join to include non-matches. I've also swapped the tables around so the Results are joined onto the Subjects, but as pointed out in the comments, this is a matter of preference. The key thing is that you need to select the Subjects.Id rather than the ID in the Results table, which would return nothing in the event of a non-match.

Comment: In this case, I'm fairly confident that "A Left Join B" and "B Right Join A" are equivalent. The issue was simply taht he was using SubjectsId instead of ID, which meant that he has no ID when there were no matches.

Comment: Correct, but I've always been taught to use left outer, so it's simply a matter of preference. I've edited my answer to reference your comment.

Comment: Thanks Everyone, Results.Subject ID was actually a typo when making the simplified example but it helped me to see where I was going wrong as with my actual code so thanks! My actual code was cross referencing the same table 3 times for different reasons (Group By requiring finding a specific instance of a row) and some of the joins were wonky. In breaking it down to make the example I figured out why it was not working!